# Zend PHP simple AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I've searched SO for an answer to this, and even though I can find answers relating to the Zend framework and AJAX, I am not able to fix my problem.

I want to do delete a table row via an AJAX POST method.

My reason for doing this is that my web developer can longer make changes to my project, so I am having to step in and attempt to do some things myself (so I'll overlook somewhat obvious things).

**HTML:**

```
<a class="btn btn-danger delete_request_button" data-rid="<?php echo $row['id']?>" data-did="<?php echo $row['dealer_id']?>" href="#delete_request_button" data-toggle="modal">Delete</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.delete_request_button').click(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-rid');
    jQuery('#request_id').val(id);

    jQuery.post('<?php echo $this->baseUrl("requests/delete")?>', { id: id }, function(response) {

    }).complete(function(){
        alert(id + ' deleted')
    });
});
```

---

**Controller:**

```
function deleteAction() 
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if($request->isPost()) {
        $this->model_dealer->deleteRequest($id);
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function deleteRequest($id)
{
    $where = $db->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);

    $db->delete('dealers_vehicle_requests', $where);
}
```

**And here is my table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `dealers_vehicle_requests` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dealer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  `requested_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT 'P',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

I realise that this is probably a mashup of horrible code, but I'm using SO as a last resort to try and solve this problem.

Thanks!

---

**Edit: fixed**

**Model:**

```
public function deleteRequest($id)
{
    $where = $this->dealers_subscriptions->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);
    $this->dealers_vehicle_requests->update(array('status' => 'D'), $where);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function deleteAction() 
{
    $request = $this->_request;
    $id = $request->getParam('id');

    if($request->isPost()) {
        $this->model_dealer->deleteRequest($id);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Everything else kept the same.

Thanks to all that helped with this question.

Comment: Nothing is actually being deleted from the database. I get an alert, for example "9 deleted", but when I refresh the row is still there and the database is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function deleteRequest($id)
{
    $where = $db->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);

    $db->delete('dealers_vehicle_requests', $where);
}
```

Did you forget to initialize `$db` variable there ?

Try to add:

`$db  = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();`

**EDIT**

Also try this JS :

```
jQuery('.delete_request_button').click(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-rid');
    jQuery('#request_id').val(id);

    jQuery.post('<?php echo $this->baseUrl("requests/delete")?>', { id: id }, function(response) {
        alert(id + ' deleted')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added that line, but it still doesn't seem to be working. For what it's worth, I do get an alert upon pressing the button (with the correct id too), it just doesn't seem to be communicating with the server. **Edit:** In a model created by my developer, he uses this syntax: `$this->dealers_vehicle_requests->insert(array('dealer_id' => $id, 'message' => $message));`